# Como usar o View Animation

Tags: android, android-layout

Gostaria de saber como utilizaria a `View Animation` ,para simular uma GIF.

Por exemplo:  eu tenho um foto de uma espada, essa espada tá pra cima, então fazer algo como que ela vá para a direita, sentido horário,dando uma volta e voltando a sua posição de origem.

Alguém já trabalhou desta maneira?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Android disponibiliza vários tipos de animações que se podem aplicar a uma *ImageView*. Aquela que se aplica neste seu caso é a [RotateAnimation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html).

A sua utilização é feita em 3 passos:

1 - Criar um objecto do tipo *RotateAnimation*

```
//Cria uma animação de rotação desde de 0º a 360º com o eixo de rotação no centro da imagem.
RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f,
                                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, 
                                                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
```

2 - Definir as propriedades da animação.

```
// 3 segundos.
long tempo = 3000;

//Define que a animação se processa de forma linear
animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

//Define o tempo da animação 
animation.setDuration(tempo);
```

3 - Iniciá-la.

```
imageView.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: Eu consegui , mas usando um arquivo XML , e lá eu configurei isso que vc digitou , mas na class java eu usei um Objeto Animation, usei o metodo Load, e vinculei com o XML que criei